# Why don't I see the horizontal scroll bar when I have set the policy to HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED

Tags: java, swing, jtable, jscrollpane, jscrollbar

I have added `jTable` inside the `jScrollPane` as :

```
    public Scenario_One() {
      initComponents();
      jScrollPane1.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED);
      jScrollPane1.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED);
    }

    private void initComponents() {
       .
       .
       jScrollPane1.setViewportView(jTable1);
       .
       .
    }
```

The text to displayed in one single row is too large so I had to use horizontal scroll bars. But even after setting the policy to `as needed` I do not see the horizontal scroll bars. What could be the reason for this ?

Comment: You don't see because it's not "NEEDED".  The view's width does not extend beyond the width of the scroll pane's view width.  Try setting the table's [`autoResizeMode`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JTable.html#setAutoResizeMode%28int%29) to `AUTO_RESIZE_OFF` and try resizing one or more of the columns beyond the width of the scroll pane

Comment: @MadProgrammer I have to manually do this ! Then of course this is not a good thing. I thought that somehow I will receive an output that will automatically put the horizontal bar as per the size of row of table

Comment: Try setting the `horizontalScrollBarPolicy` to `HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS` - you could could update the column model with the width of the column as needed

Comment: @MadProgrammer i tried but in this case it is almost the same thing. I have to manually extend the column to the right

Comment: @Y.E.P If you want your columns to be bigger, set their minimum and preferred size.

Comment: The size of the table is determined by the size of the columns, take a look at the column model and try setting the preferred size of the columns you want to expand. The table isn't going to do it for you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like this...

[image]

```
public class TestTableColumns {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new TestTableColumns();
    }

    public TestTableColumns() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
                } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
                } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
                } catch (UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                }

                DefaultTableModel model =new DefaultTableModel(
                                new Object[][] {
                                    {"1", "2"},
                                    {"11", "21"},
                                    {"12", "22"},
                                    {"13", "23"},
                                    {"14", "24"},
                                    {"15", "25"},
                                    {"16", "26"},
                                    {"17", "27"},
                                    {"18", "28"}}, 
                                new Object[] {
                                    "Small", "Big"});

                JTable table = new JTable(model);
                table.setShowHorizontalLines(true);
                table.setShowVerticalLines(true);
                table.setShowGrid(true);
                table.setGridColor(Color.DARK_GRAY);
                table.setAutoResizeMode(JTable.AUTO_RESIZE_OFF);
                table.getColumn("Small").setPreferredWidth(100);
                table.getColumn("Small").setWidth(12);
                table.getColumn("Big").setPreferredWidth(400);
                table.getColumn("Big").setWidth(100);

                JFrame frame = new JFrame();
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
                frame.add(new JScrollPane(table));
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }            
        });
    }    
}
```

The width of the view port is dictated by the width of the component it contains.  For a `JTable`, that is determined by the size of the columns and the auto size policy

Answer (score 3):

As @MadProgrammer already commented, the property that controls the table sizing behaviour inside a JScrollPane is the autoResizeMode. Basically, there a two options:

- autoResizeOff: the columns are always shown at their prefWidth, showing/hiding the horizontal scrollBar as needed. If their total width is less than the viewport width, the trailing space is left free (showing the viewport)
- all the others: the columns are sized such that the total width of the table fits into the scrollPane, the horizontal scrollBar is never shown

The (intuitive) expectation that the table "fits" into the viewport until the columns get too wide to be fully shown and then automatically allow scrolling is *not* supported in core JTable. JXTable (contained in the [SwingX project](http://swingx.java.net)) provides an additional sizing option for doing it.